# Calling java script chrome and firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, browser

I am calling this script in a for loop

```
<script src="../../../data/novus/src/models/multiChart.js"></script>.
```

In firefox, the script is called for every iteration of the loop  BUT

In chrome it only calls it once.

Is there a way to make chrome behave like firefox does. Am I doing something wrong with the way I'm calling it?

Thanks for your help

Comment: this is not you are calling. this is you are referring the script. add the content of this file

Comment: That is what I meant, sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: Have you tried to put the loop inside the script and call the script only once?

Comment: I have tried that. I am using this to make multiple graphs on a page, if I call the script only once, it uses the same data for every graph.

Answer (score 0):

Caching?

Try this instead of your tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var cacheBuster = new Date().getTime();
    var s = '<script src="../../../data/novus/src/models/multiChart.js?_=' + cacheBuster +  '"></script>';
    document.write(s);
</script>
```

Comment: It calls it but it doesnt seem to use it because no graphs appear.

Comment: So does this solve your original question? Does chrome "call" the script as many times as the loop count? Can you put a 'console.log' inside the js file to see if it actually does get included in as many times?

Comment: Yea, this does include the file several times